# Scala macros: Generate factory or ctor for Java Pojo

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I'm currently working with reasonably large code base where new code is written in scala, but where a lot of old Java code remains. In particular there are a lot of java APIs we have to talk to. The old code uses simple Java Pojos with public non-final fields, **without any methods or constructors**, e.g:

```
public class MyJavaPojo {
    public String myField1;
    public MyOtheJavaPojo myField2;
}
```

Note that we dont have the option of adding helper methods or constructors to these types. These are currently created like old c-structs (pre-named parameters) like this:

```
val myPojo = new MyJavaPojo
myPojo.myField1 = ...
myPojo.myField2 = ...
```

**Because of this, it's very easy to forget about assigning one of the fields**, especially when we suddenly add new fields to the MyJavaPojo class, the compiler wont complain that I've left one field to null.

NOTE: We don't have the option of modifying the java types/adding constructors the normal way. We also don't want to start creating lots and lots of manually created helper functions for object creation - We would really like to find a solution based on scala macros instead of possible!

What I would like to do would be to create a macro that generates either a constructor-like method for my Pojos or a macro that creates a factory, allowing for named parameters. (Basically letting a macro do the work instead of creating a gazillion manually written helper methods in scala).

Do you know of any way to do this with scala macros? (I'm certain it's possible, but I've never written a scala macro in my life)

Desired API alternative 1:

```
val myPojo = someMacro[MyJavaPojo](myField1 = ..., myField2 = ...)
```

Desired API alternative 2

```
val factory = someMacro[MyJavaPojo]
val myPojo = factory.apply(myField1 = ..., myField2 = ...)
```

NOTE/Important: Named parameters!

I'm looking for either a ready-to-use solution or hints as to where I can read up on making one.

All ideas and input appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [scala-beanutils](https://github.com/yetu/scala-beanutils).

```
@beanCompanion[MyJavaPojo] object MyScalaPojo

MyScalaPojo(...)
```

It probably won't work directly, as you classes are not beans and it's only been made for Scala 2.10, but the source code is < 200 lines and should give you an idea of where to start.

Comment: Cool project. Thanks.